# Adding custom schema to 389 Directory Server

Tags: ldap

I'm trying auth against ldap (389 DS) using ssh public key.

I have read https://github.com/AndriiGrytsenko/openssh-ldap-publickey (and many more)

The first step is add the objectclass to the ldap.

Based in https://github.com/AndriiGrytsenko/openssh-ldap-publickey/blob/master/misc/openssh-lpk-openldap.schema (**designed to openldap**).  I have created my own ldif file for 389 DS.

Looks like this

```
# 60sshlpk.ldif
# ldapPublicKey
#
# LDAP Public Key Patch schema for use with openssh-ldappubkey
#                              useful with PKA-LDAP also
#
# Author: Eric AUGE <eau@phear.org>
#
# Based on the proposal of : Mark Ruijter
#
################################################################################
#
dn: cn=schema
#
################################################################################
#
attributetype: (
  1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.1.13
  NAME 'sshPublicKey'
  DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH Public key'
  EQUALITY octetStringMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40
  )
#
################################################################################
#
objectclass: (
  1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0
  NAME 'ldapPublicKey'
  SUP top
  AUXILIARY
  DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass'
  MUST ( sshPublicKey $ uid )
  )
#
################################################################################
#
```

I have put new scheme in /etc/dirsrv/slapd-dir/schema/ and restarted the server.

File  is fine loaded but...

```
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - Entry "cn=schema" has unknown object class "(   1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass' MUST ( sshPublicKey $ uid )  )"
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - Entry "cn=schema" has unknown object class "( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass' MUST ( sshPublicKey $ uid )  )"
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - Entry "cn=schema" has unknown object class "( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK   objectclass' MUST ( sshPublicKey $ uid )  )"
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - Entry "cn=schema" has unknown object class "( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass' MUST ( sshPublicKey $ uid )  )"
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - 389-Directory/1.2.10.4 B2013.059.1953 starting up
[25/Dec/2014:18:40:47 +0100] - slapd started.  Listening on All Interfaces port 389 for LDAP requests
```

I need new OIDs for 389 DS right?

If answer is yes, somebody know how to proceed??

Thanks and merry christmas!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer and isn't  related with OIDs

In my ldif I'm using ***attributetype*** and ***objectclass*** instead ***attributeTypes*** and ***objectClasses***

The keywords are differents in openldap and 389 DS.

Comment: Additionally to this answer - because this got me: you need to capitalise the letters (T in attributeTypes and C in objectClasses) but **also add an 's' character to the end)**